# Only one font awesome icon displaying correctly using [ngClass] conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

I am building a user profile where the user can submit links to his or her social media accounts. Each account is represented with a clickable link. Which icon should be chosen is decided by multiple conditions in [ngClass], heres the code:

```
    <div *ngIf="socialMediaLinkList.length > 0" class="topic">
            <strong>can be followed on:</strong>
                <a *ngFor="let socialMediaLink of socialMediaLinkList" [href]="socialMediaLink.link">
                    <i [title]="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType" 
                    [ngClass]="{
                        'fa fa-youtube':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE',
                        'fa fa-facebook-official':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'FACEBOOK',
                        'fa fa-twitter':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'TWITTER',
                        'fa fa-reddit':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'REDDIT',
                        'fa fa-pinterest':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'PINTEREST',
                        'fa fa-linkedin-square':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'LINKEDIN',
                        'fa fa-instagram':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'INSTAGRAM',
                        'fa fa-google-plus':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'GOOGLE_PLUS',
                        'fa fa-tumblr-square':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'TUMBLR',
                        'fa fa-vimeo-square':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'VIMEO',
                        'fa fa-vk':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'VKONTAKTE',
                        'fa fa-weibo':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'WEIBO',
                        'fa fa-renren':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'RENREN',
                        'fa fa-odnoklassniki':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'ODNOKLASSNIKI',
                        'fa fa-flickr':socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'FLICKR'
                }"></i>
                </a> 
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </div>
```

The problem is that only the last icon in the condition list is displaying correctly, all the others are displayed like uniform blocks like so:

[image]

And this is only because FLICKR happens to be in the list of randomly generated social media accounts. If FLICKR is not part of that list then all the social media account icons will be blocks. Things change if for example i swap the condition for ODNOKLASSNIKI with FLICKR, making ODNOKLASSNIKI be the last. Now Odnoklassniki is the only icon that will display correctly.

I've followed the ngClass example here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/ and i as far as i'm concerned i'm not making any errors.

Heres how the list is being initialized using the SocialMediaLink class

```
export class SocialMediaLink{
  constructor(public socialMediaType:string, public link: string){}
}

if(this.aboutSection.socialMediaAccounts !== undefined){
    this.selectedSocialMediaAccounts = new Map<SocialMedia,string>((<any>Object).entries(this.aboutSection.socialMediaAccounts));
    this.selectedSocialMediaAccounts.forEach((link: string, socialMediaType:SocialMedia) => 
    this.socialMediaLinkList.push(new SocialMediaLink(socialMediaType.toString(), link)));
}
```

Can anyone tell me how i can remedy this problem? Thank you

EDIT: this is the font awesome cdn i'm using @import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

Comment: Does the data returned correctly?

Comment: are all the socialMediaTypes fields populated with correct values? Yes. I can see sowhen i hover over each icon, The title then appears and this has the socialMediaType value as its content

Comment: Which is your version of font awesome? at least for versions 5.x+ there seems to be different declarations for example facebook its not like that https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=facebook

Comment: i'm using 4.7.0

Comment: @import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `ngClass` binding, if a condition is `true`, it sets the `fa` class. However, the following conditions, which are `false`, remove it. That is why the `fa` class is preserved only when the last condition is `true`.

You should set the common class `fa` outside of the conditional `ngClass` binding:

```
<i [title]="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType" 
  class="fa" 
  [ngClass]="{
    'fa-youtube': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE',
    'fa-facebook-official': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'FACEBOOK',
    'fa-twitter': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'TWITTER',
    'fa-reddit': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'REDDIT',
    'fa-pinterest': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'PINTEREST',
    'fa-linkedin-square': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'LINKEDIN',
    'fa-instagram': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'INSTAGRAM',
    'fa-google-plus': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'GOOGLE_PLUS',
    'fa-tumblr-square': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'TUMBLR',
    'fa-vimeo-square': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'VIMEO',
    'fa-vk': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'VKONTAKTE',
    'fa-weibo': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'WEIBO',
    'fa-renren': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'RENREN',
    'fa-odnoklassniki': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'ODNOKLASSNIKI',
    'fa-flickr': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'FLICKR'
  }"></i>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbxbct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

---

An alternative solution is to keep `fa` in the `ngClass` binding, and to set its condition to `true`:

```
<i [title]="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType" 
  [ngClass]="{
    'fa': true,
    'fa-youtube': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE',
    ...
  }"></i>
```

Comment: Nice, but can you explain how the fa is removed from the previous one? even the condition looks good

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien - If the value is `'YOUTUBE'`, the first condition sets `fa fa-youtube`. But the second conditon (for `'FACEBOOK'`) is false, and it removes `fa fa-facebook-official`. So, `fa` is removed in the process.

Comment: Oh, the engine is so weird, I thought it should take the whole string as a condition, not separate them like that. Thank you anyway @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach above from @ConnorsFun and unfortunately it didn't work for me.  This is my code for both of the approaches above (using font awesome 5 in which prefix 'fa' has been changed to 'fas):

```
<i class='fas' [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': filterCategories[0]['collapse'], 'fa-minus': !filterCategories[0]['collapse']}"></i> {{filterCategories[0]['name']}}

<i [ngClass]="{'fas': true, 'fa-plus': filterCategories[0]['collapse'], 'fa-minus': !filterCategories[0]['collapse']}"></i> {{filterCategories[0]['name']}}
```

The code is supposed to change the icon from fa-minus (when value of `filterCategories[0]['collapse']` is false) to fa-plus (when value of `filterCategories[0]['collapse']` is true), but the icon remains stuck at fa-minus regardless of the `filterCategories[0]['collapse']` value.

An alternative that I used is having multiple  elements with ngIf statements.  For example:

```
<span *ngIf="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE'><i class= 'fas fa-youtube'></span>
<span *ngIf="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === FACEBOOK><i class= 'fas fa-facebook-official'></span>
```

and so on …

Even though this approach works well, I personally prefer the response above from @ConnonrsFan if I can get it to work.

Comment: it would be best to turn this into a new question where you make a reference to ConnorFans's answer :) You will be much more likely to get an answer if you turn it into a new SO question.

Comment: @Maurice - thanks for the suggestion.  I was also intending for my answer to be available to others looking for an alternative solution to this issue, hence this post.